# Android AppWidgetProvider not receiving local broadcasts

Tags: android, broadcast, android-appwidget

When I send local broadcast from a service (extending IntentService) it's not received in onReceive in my AppWidgetProvider, but the same broadcast is received if not sent locally. Is it normal?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that in my AndroidManifest I have `<action>` inside `<intent-filter>` for AppWidgetProvider `<receiver>` like this:

```
<receiver android:name="MyAppWidget">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <action android:name="my.package.MY_ACTION" />
</intent-filter>
...
```

and in MyAppWidget extending AppWidgetProvider in 'onReceive' I have:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("my.package.MY_ACTION")) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If by "local broadcast", you mean `LocalBroadcastManager`, an `AppWidgetProvider` will not respond to those by default. An `AppWidgetProvider` is listening to system broadcasts, by means of its `<receiver>` element.

Moreover, this should not be necessary. There is nothing magic about an `AppWidgetProvider` — it is merely a designated place for the system to let you know about changes in app widget state. You can update your app widget contents from any portion of your app, by means of `AppWidgetManager`.

Comment: What do you mean by "AppWidgetProvider will not respond to those by default"? Do I have to use sendBroadcast(Intent) instead of LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(Intent) to send any custom (non-system) broadcast to AppWidgetProvider?

Comment: @MarekJ.: "Do I have to use sendBroadcast(Intent)" -- yes, or do not send a broadcast at all, per the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for help! I wonder why isn't it anywhere in AppWidgetProvider documentation that local broadcasts are not received?

Comment: @MarekJ.: You cannot document all possible negatives. An `AppWidgetProvider` does not integrate with a microwave oven, either. :-)